# $(...).formSelect is not a function

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, html-select, materialize

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkA8J.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KzEK.png)Am using materializecss plugins for forms. Its working fine in html page but while I used in .Net core MVC view select option dropdown is not working. its shows error in console..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyz0F.png)

'code'

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="~/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('select').formSelect();

        $('.datepicker').datepicker();

    });

</script>
```

```
<div class="container body">

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12  form-group has-feedback">

        <div class="input-field">

            <i class="material-icons prefix">assignment</i>

            <select id="ddlAssignment">

                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>

                <option value="1">Carolinas, Main</option>

                <option value="2">Option 2</option>

                <option value="3">Option 3</option>

            </select>

            <label>Assignment</label>

        </div>


    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6  form-group has-feedback">

        <div class="input-field">

            <i class="material-icons prefix">event_note</i>

            <input type="text" class="datepicker">

            <label class="dated-lbl" for="icon_prefixsd">Service Date</label>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Can you show some of your code? Hard to understand the issue without seeing what you have done already...

Comment: :) can you please edit your question with your code and use the formatting tools? Bit hard to read in a comment!!!

Comment: I uploaded the screenshot of code please check once .....

Comment: screentshots of code are unhelpful - sorry. Difficult to reproduce the issue you are having if we cannot copy your code...some helpful links https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry for that its shows error while i upload the code...now i upload the code please check and review on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a test using [Materialize plugins](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) in .NET Core MVC view page, which work well on my side, please refer to it.

```
<div class="container body">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12  form-group has-feedback">

        <div class="input-field">

            <i class="material-icons prefix">assignment</i>

            <select id="ddlAssignment">

                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>

                <option value="1">Carolinas, Main</option>

                <option value="2">Option 2</option>

                <option value="3">Option 3</option>

            </select>

            <label>Assignment</label>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6  form-group has-feedback">

        <div class="input-field">

            <i class="material-icons prefix">event_note</i>

            <input type="text" class="datepicker">

            <label class="dated-lbl" for="icon_prefixsd">Service Date</label>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('select').formSelect();

        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    </script>
}
```

You can create a new view page and include materialize from CDN as I did in above sample, then test if it can work well within your project. Besides, to check if any conflicts with other jquery files (referenced in layout file) cause the issue, please set `Layout = null;` to use no layout for your view page.